# How can all organisms take human birth ? Will it not be injustice?

Tags: birth

Total number of human beings to have ever lived = [107 billion.](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-16870579)

Total number of just insects currently living = [10 quintillion](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+insects+in+the+world) i.e. 10 billion billion .

Number of plants and other animals will also be high.

Number of micro-organisms will be higher.

So, by probability most organism will never be able to attain human birth. As in few billion years life will not exist on earth. And most probably human beings will become extinct in few years.

Will it not be injustice to organisms who were never able to take human birth ?

Comment: Yes. As per Hinduism, there's nothing called as the final End. It's an eternal unending cycle. Was, Is, and Will be. So every Jiva will most probably get a chance to be a Human or other specie as per the governing Karma Theory.

Comment: You are asking for opinions. It is not injustice as there have been an infinite number of kalpas before and there will be an infinite number of kalpas in the future. 'Organisms' are material bodies. All the jivas that pass through all these different physical bodies will sooner or later attain human birth.

Comment: Simple.. this statement : *"Total number of human beings to have ever lived = 107 billion."* - is wrong. It is infinite

Comment: *Will it not be injustice to organisms who were never able to take human birth ?* --- How do you know that they were never able to take human birth? What if they all lived as humans once upon a time?

Answer (score 1):

Phenomena of Karmaa and Janmaa bear cause and effect  relationship, aquire  the problem in the analogy of tree and seed,that  does not answer the question what came first.
ref.  cited in HH Shankaras
sarva vedanta sidhanta Sara sangraha verse 511

> karrmana jayate jantuhu
> karmanaiva praliyate
> karmanaha karyamevaisha
> janma mrutyu parampara

By all knowledge in scriptures, By sacrifices, By elaborate rituals etc
-yet, without the realization of Self, there shall be no liberation for
the Jiva, from this cycle of karma janma  of not even in the life times of a hundred Brahmas put together.  cited in Vivekachudamani Verse 6

> vadantu śāstrāṇi yajantu devān
> kurvantu karmāṇi bhajantu devatāḥ
> ātmaikyabodhena vināpi muktiḥ
> na sidhyati brahmaśatāntare'pi ||

Demographic data may not be relevant here since there are infinite number of jivas which includes a blade of grass as well as Brahma the creator.so any math op with infinity results in infinity .

Story of Jada Bharatha in Narada Purana reflects this idea

https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/naradapurana8.html